# Using "using strict" as a backup for "use strong"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8, use-strict

Is there someway to use `"use strong";` and have `"use strict";` used as a backup?  Since it appears like Google Chrome is the only browser to support `"use strong";` at the moment.

Comment: Did you try `"use strict"; "use strong";` in any order? Not sure if environments would consider the second one as directive or not.

Comment: Is `"use strong"` already an official proposal?

Comment: @FelixKling: According to [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-directive-prologues-and-the-use-strict-directive), both should work (and in any order)

Answer (score 1):

You could always wrap your code in an immediately-invoked function expression, with "use strict" outside of it and "use strong" inside (so it takes precedence if the browser supports it):

```
"use strict"
(function(){
    "use strong";
    //your code here
})();
```

Comment: But there's no need to do this.